# How and how long will the metallic ball move?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge

We have suspended an *electrically neutral* metallic ball from an insulated string between two parallel metallic plates that are oppositely charged but have the same magnitude. So, the charge in this system is conserved.

We put the metallic ball in contact with one of the plated (any one of them) and then leave it to move freely. How would the ball move and till how long would it move?

---

[image: Reference Image]

---

Here's what I think would happen :

Let's assume that the metal plate on the left has a charge of $(+x)$ $e$ and the one on the right has a charge of $(-x)$ $e$ and that the metallic ball is put in contact with the metallic plate on the right.

So, net charge between the ball and the plate = $0+(-x) = 0-x = (-x)$ $e$, so after contact, both of them will have a charge of $\Big (\dfrac {-x}{2} \Big )$ $e$. And then, the ball would move towards the metallic plate on the right with a charge of $\Big (\dfrac {-x}{2} \Big )$ $e$ because the ball being *negatively* charged and the plate on the left being *positively* charged will attract each other. Now, the net charge between the ball and the plate on the left will be $\Bigg ((x)+\Big (\dfrac {-x}{2} \Big ) \Bigg )e = \Big (\dfrac {+x}{2} \Big )$ $e$. So, after the contact, both the metallic ball and the plate on the left will have a charge of $\Big (\dfrac {+x}{4} \Big )$ $e$. Now, the ball being positively charged and the metallic plate on the right being negatively charged $\Bigg (\Big (\dfrac {-x}{2} \Big )$ $e$ $\Bigg )$ will attract each other and the same process will follow.

So, according to me, the ball would move *infinitely* and will keep on acquiring a charge of $\Big ( \pm \dfrac {x}{2^n} \Big )$ $e$, where $n \in \Bbb N$

Let me know if I'm right/wrong, thanks!

Comment: I would question the factor of 2.  I do not think the charge would be equally shared between the plate and the ball.

Comment: Doesn't that happen when objects charge through conduction?

Comment: As I learned it, the magnitude of charge on both the bodies after conduction is the same

Comment: I'm curious.  what does "b / n" mean?  I've never seen that, and I can't figure it out from context.

Comment: @garyp I'm sorry, I meant between... :). Will avoid abbreviations from now on...

Comment: Charged conductors in contact will come to the same potential. The quantity of charge on each will depend on their size and shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each full swing, the ball is picking up electrons from the negative plate and delivering them to the positive plate.  If the charge in the system is conserved, then the charge on each plate is decreasing. The charge picked up from the negative plate by the ball will be proportional to the charge remaining on that plate, so the rate of decrease will be a stepped exponential. (In theory never reaching zero.)

Comment: So, the answer is *infinity*, right? By the way, I really liked the way you turned my mathematical explanation to verbal explanation.Thanks!